# Prove that T = I with Linear Transformations.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $T \in L(V)$ and $T^2 = I$ and -1 is not an eigenvalue of T. Prove that T = I.

What I tried was:

Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of T such that $T(v) = \lambda v$

Then we know that

$T(T(v)) = \lambda T(v) = \lambda^2$

This means that $\lambda^2 = I$, but I don't know how to proceed from there, help?

Comment: I think you mean $\lambda^2 = 1$; $\lambda^2$ is a number while $I$ is a matrix, they can't be equal.

Comment: You have showed that $\lambda^2 I = I$. Solve for $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T(T(v))=\lambda T(v) = \lambda^2v$. At the same time, $T(T(v))=v$, so we have $\lambda^2=1 \implies \lambda = 1$, since $-1$ is excluded a priori. Now, what does that say about $T$?

Comment: You've shown that $1$ is the only eigenvalue. How do you know that $T$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: Good point. I suppose the approach by user84413 show how to handle this problem more precisely, although the OP apparently found some use for my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$
                 T(T-I) = T^{2}-T=I-T=(-1)(T-I).
$$
Because $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$, then $T-I=0$ is the only conclusion.

Comment: It's $T^2 = I$, not $T^2 = T$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, you did take a careful look at what I used? I used $T^{2}=I$. That happened at the second = in my equation string.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did.  Sorry about that.  Cool idea!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let A be the matrix representing T with respect to a basis for V.
Then $A^2=I$ and A does not have -1 as an eigenvalue, so A+I is invertible since it does not have 0 as an eigenvalue.

Then $A^2=I\Rightarrow (A-I)(A+I)=O\Rightarrow (A-I)(A+I)(A+I)^{-1}=O(A+I)^{-1}\Rightarrow A-I=O\Rightarrow A=I$.

Answer (score 0):

$(T-I)(T+I)=T^2-I=0$, then $V=\ker(T-I)\oplus\ker(T+I)$ ($T-I$ and $T+I$ are co-primes  ) ,as $\ker(T+I)=0$ we have $V=\ker(T-I)$, then $T=I$